# Android Emulation Rendering Issues

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using Apache Cordova (formerly PhoneGap) to whip up a quick WebView app and I am getting issues with the rending on my laptop. Its a crummy 'ol Latitude E6410 so maybe its just too underpowered to run this. I searched around for quite some time and haven't found anyone else experiencing this issue.

Here's a screenshot of the problem: http://imgur.com/JwqsF8G

Not a real game breaker, but if anyone has any knowledge as to why this is happening I'd be super grateful.